# How to provide an anonymous copy of work online?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, online-publication, anonymity

It may seem odd, but I need to put an anonymous part of my work (an algorithm) online.

Well, it should be available online as I want to refer to it in a single-blind submission (but not as the contributions), and it should be anonymous as I want to introduce it (as the contribution) in another conference submission (with double-blind review). Since the submission deadlines are close to each other I want to handle it like this.

Is there a way to put it online with anonymous author names (arXiv does not allow it) so it could also be searchable via google?

I will remove it or update it with full names after the paper review process is finished.

Comment: It might help understand what sort of solution is viable if we know why you need this. Usually, work is only submitted one place at a time.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it's an algorithm that should be introduced in a theoretical paper (with double-blind review) and should be used in a practical paper as well  (but not as a contribution). and the reviewing periods of conferences overlap!

Comment: Could you not just cite the first paper as "(in review)"? It doesn't break the double-blind anonymity unless the same person is reviewing both, which seems rather unlikely unless you are working in a very small specialism.

Comment: Why not GitHub?

Comment: @SylvainRibault is it possible to be anonymous on GitHub?

Comment: @Bob Just create an account without using your real name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the work to vixra.org which is similar to arxiv but with fewer boundaries. Maybe it does not have the reputation of arxiv, but i used it for anonymous uploading of my work.

Comment: github (or gitlab, or both if you are afraid someone will try taking it down) lets you do the same as vixra but comes without the image of crankery. Then there is [zenodo](https://zenodo.org/).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Those would make good answers.